# Ruby equivalent to PHPs urlencode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, iso-8859-1

I need to convert a URL in Ruby which contains the character "ö".

In PHP, urlencode returns %F6 for ö which seems to be the Hex-value for "ö" in ISO 8859.

I tried several different methods but none of them returned the correct character:

- CGI.escape 'ö' -> %C3%B6
- URI.encode 'o' -> %C3%B6
- ERB::Util.url_encode 'ö' -> %C3%B6
- 'ö'.force_encoding('iso-8859-1') -> \xC3\xB

What method should I use to get the desired output?

-e-

Additional requirement:

I only need to convert these characters in the path of the url. Colons, slashes etc. should remain the same:

[http://example.com/this/is/an/ö](http://example.com/this/is/an/%C3%B6)

will be

http://example.com/this/is/an/%F6

Comment: have you tried this `'ö'.encode("ISO-8859-1")` ?

Comment: _"In PHP, urlencode returns %F6 for ö"_ – it depends. If you pass an UTF-8 string to PHP's `urlencode` it also returns `%C3%B6`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ruby uses UTF-8 strings by default:

```
str = 'ö'

str.encoding
#=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

If you want an ISO 8859 encoded string in Ruby, you have to convert it:

```
str.encode('ISO-8859-1')
#=> "\xF6"
```

to URL-encode a string, there's `CGI.escape`:

```
require 'cgi'

CGI.escape(str.encode('ISO-8859-1'))
#=> "%F6"
```

to encode an URL, use [`URI.escape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-escape):

```
require 'uri'

url = 'http://example.com/this/is/an/ö'
URI.escape(url.encode('ISO-8859-1'))
#=> "http://example.com/this/is/an/%F6"
```

Comment: Now the problem is that every character in the url gets converted. For example a frontslash is %2F. Is there a better way than to split the url into it's parts and convert only the actual path?

Comment: @SanoJ your question was about `ö`, your didn't mention any slashes. Maybe you could edit your question and explain what you are trying to do. An example would probably help.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution

```
converter = Encoding::Converter.new("utf-8", "iso-8859-1")
CGI.escape(converter.convert('ö'))

=> "%F6"
```